# Postgresql -- cleanup HTML tags in middle of string

Tags: html, regex, postgresql

If I have this in a Postgresql 9.1 column:

```
foo foo <th id="ddd"> foo foo <th id="www"> foo
```

And I want it to update to this:

```
foo foo <th> foo foo <th> foo
```

I've tried regex_replace, but I have not succeeded.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24417204

Comment: Peter: Funny you add that two years later. Because I ended up going in a direction similar to one of the comments in the Q (I actually used the libxslt in Postgres). They warned me that one should parse with a parser, not with regex. At first I did not heed, then I learned my lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  a character varying NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

You can use the following regexp_replace:

```
update table1 set a = regexp_replace(a, '(.*?)<(\w+)\s+.*?>(.*)', '\1<\2>\3', 'g');
```

The `'g'` flag indicates to replace all matching patterns, not only the first one.

With this input:

```
foo foo <th id="ddd"> foo foo <th id="www"> foo<div id="hey">
```

I get the following ouput:

```
foo foo <th> foo foo <th> foo<div>
```