# How count words of plain text in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plaintext

I have a few columns with html strings in a postgres 9.5 database. I want to count the words without html tags and their values to get the length of the plain text for each row.

Is there a stored procedure or another way to do this?

**Edit:**
existing sample text in one field:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum: </p><p><br/></p><p align="center"><img src="d9b4c473-08ac-4cd8-883d-86ac30ee9044.png" width="287" height="192"/></p><p><br/></p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#86b920">consetetur</span> sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l. </p><p><br/></p><p><br/></p><p><br/></p>
```

---

expected output for this text:

```
Lorem Ipsum: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l.
```

At best an additional column with a word count of this text

Comment: You need to provide examples of what your text looks like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12049905/330315 especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46757280/330315

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [regexp_split_to_table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html) - with the right regex expression you can break all words from the html and return them as a table.